# html responsive webpage code issue using visual studio code html5

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm developing a website and I'm struggling with the nav bar and my main issue is that the html responsive code is not working with me i don't know why can someone guide me?

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

this is my responsive html code I only write it in html page I should write another responsive code in css?

Comment: Will be impossible to tell without your code. Please post an [example].

Comment: do you even know what this line does? it is part of a responsive concept but does not make a website responsive at all (at least on its own).

Comment: I'm student and this is my first web page and in  the college they teach us this line only that this line will make the code responsive, if you have idea can  you guide me? because this is my project for this semester and the dr dos't help me.

Answer (score -1):

Then you start your yiur html filelike this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

meta viewport is important but you need to add @media with breakpoint that you need in your css file, for exemple like this:

```
.container{
width: 90%
background: red;
height: 100px;

}   
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .container {
        width: 80%;
        background: green;
        height: 200px;

    }
}
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) you will find more informations.

Comment: meta viewport is not important. It just ensures that software-pixel is the same as hardware-pixels. You just need then to support resolutions down to a min-width of 320px.